# I have some illegal expressions in my code but I don't know how to fix it

Tags: syntax-error, pascal

This is my code, I have illegal expressions at line 39/45, 40/50, 51/45, 52/36 and fatal: Unexpected end of file at line 64 It would be very helpful if some you will teach me a few things about pascal.

```
Program PatientRecords;
{Aurthor: Vincent Lopez,
February 16,2015,
Program will read names, age and treatment cost for at least ten patients}

Var {declaration of variables}

   Name: array [1..11] of string;
   Age: array [1..11] of integer;
   T_Cost: array [1..11] of real;
   G_Cost: array [1..11] of real;
   P_Cost: array [1..11] of real;
   Count: integer;

Begin {The program starts here}

  {Initialization of variables}

  For count := 1 to 10 DO
  WriteLn('Welcome to Ministry of Health Cost of Health Care');

  WriteLn('Enter the name of the patient');

  Readln(name[count]);

  Writeln('Enter the age of the patient');

  Readln(Age[count]);

  Writeln('Enter the treatment cost for patient');

  Readln(T_cost[count]);

  IF Age>= 65 THEN

  Begin

    G_cost[count]=T_cost[count]*(100/80);
    P_cost[count]=T_cost[count]-G_cost[count];

    Writeln('Government will pay = $',G_cost[count]);
    Writeln('The patient will pay = $',P_cost[count]);

  end

  ELSE

  Begin

    G_cost[count]=T_cost[count]*(100/50);
    P_cost=T_cost-G_cost[count];

    Writeln('Government will pay = $',G_cost[count]);
    Writeln('The patient will pay = $',P_cost[count]);

    Readln;

    Writeln('Press enter to continue');

    Readln;

  END; {The program ends here}
```

Comment: So what syntax errors are you getting? The compiler tells you exactly, and there's no reason for you not to share that information with us; after all, it's right on the screen in front of you. We can't see your screen from here. Your question title should also describe the problem in a way that will be useful to future readers here who find it in a search result; *i have some errors in my code* will not be useful at all.

Comment: I don't know Pascal, but if it is case sensitive, you declared `T_Cost` but reference `T_cost`, notice the capital **C**? If this is the case, check them all.

Comment: @DonovanSolms: Pascal is not case-sensitive, so that's not the issue.

Comment: thanks for helping. It's just that I have illegal expressions in my code but I have no idea how to fix it (I'm kinda new to programming)

Comment: As I said before, the compiler tells you *exactly* which syntax error you have and what line it is located on. It's right on your screen in front of you. *Please [edit] your question and include that information for us as well; at the same time improve the title of your question to be more specific.*

Comment: Please go back and re-read the section of your textbook that introduces *assignment statements*. Carefully compare the examples there to the assignment statements that the compiler points to as errors.

Comment: See, *e.g.*, [Learn Pascal - Assignment and Operations](http://www.exam.gr/pascal/Docs/tutorial1/pas1e.html).

Answer (score 0):

One obvious error is the statement

```
 IF Age>= 65 THEN
```

Age is an array of integers, so this presumably should be

```
 IF Age[count] >= 65 THEN
```

Another obvious error is that the last line should be 'END.' with a full stop. The 'end;' which you have at the moment is aligned to the 'begin' block following the 'else' branch of the 'if age[count]' statement.

I suggest that first you learn how to run the program for one set of data, then expand it. You will discover that the 'writeln/readln' pair are in the wrong place.